# Is it possible to configure Azure Digital Twins API access for a Daemon App?

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-identity-platform, azure-digital-twins

To automate maintenance of an Azure Digital Twins instance, we require service-to-service API access so that we can use Azure middle-tier options to run as daemon apps (e.g. Logic App or Function).

However, the Azure Digitial Twins 'preview' API (resource id: 0b07f429-9f4b-4714-9392-cc5e8e80c8b0) does not support Application Permissions when registering the application in Azure Active Directory (only Delegated Permissions). However, the related Microsoft Graph API (resource id: 00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000) supports both permission types.

Is there any way currently to authenticate for access to the Azure Digital Twins API without the need for a signed-in AAD account (i.e. using 'client_credentials' grant type)?

Answer (score 0):

To use client credential flow, you need the Application permission. If there is just `Delegated Permission` defined in the API, you could just access the API with a signed-in user account, e.g. authorization code flow.

In your case, the option is [On-Behalf-Of flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow).

1. The user authenticate with the middle-tier application with authorization code flow or another login flow
2. An OAuth 2.0 On-Behalf-Of token is acquired during authentication
3. The acquired token is then used to authenticate with or call APIs that are further downstream using the On-Behalf-Of flow

For more details, check this doc - [Call Digital Twins from a middle-tier web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/digital-twins/security-authenticating-apis#call-digital-twins-from-a-middle-tier-web-api).

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but this provides a known workaround not an answer to my question. The Daemon app runs unattended on a trigger, and has no interaction with a human user. Therefore, the user cannot authenticate at the time of execution.

Comment: @ChrisLowndes If so, you can't call the api. The api was designed to expose just a delegated permission, you must use the user to authenticate.

Comment: You actually can, I have a demo running at our office that requires no human logon. I created it a while ago, and it revolves around a service principal. Let me know if you still need this.

Answer (score 0):

1. First you need to add new role (RABC) for console application which is registered in the Azure AD into azure digital twins instance.
2. Create client secret for console app.

   ```
    private static DigitalTwinsClient GetDigitalTwinsClient(string tenantId, string clientId, string clientSecret, string adtEndpoint)
    {
        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET", clientSecret);
        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("AZURE_CLIENT_ID", clientId);
        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("AZURE_TENANT_ID", tenantId);

        var tokenCredential = new DefaultAzureCredential();

        var client = new DigitalTwinsClient(
            new Uri(adtEndpoint),
            tokenCredential, new DigitalTwinsClientOptions
            { Transport = new HttpClientTransport(httpClient) });

        return client;
    }
   ```