# Not able to access azure digital twin API without user interaction

Tags: azure-digital-twins

I referred to these answers but I'm not able to authenticate Azure Digital Twins without browser interaction.

1. [How to access azure digital twin API using Service Principal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61379208/how-to-access-azure-digital-twin-api-using-service-principal)
2. [Is it possible to configure Azure Digital Twins API access for a Daemon App?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60311384/is-it-possible-to-configure-azure-digital-twins-api-access-for-a-daemon-app)

Answer (score 0):

Those two questions both refer to the Azure Digital Twins preview before it was refreshed. It is possible to access Azure Digital Twins without browser authentication. You will need the `Azure.Identity` package. I used version 1.2.2

```
var credential =
    new ClientSecretCredential("{AZURE_TENANT_ID}, "{AZURE_CLIENT_ID}", "{AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET}");
var client = new DigitalTwinsClient(new Uri("{AZURE_DIGITAL_TWINS_URL}"), credential);
```

You need to replace the values with

1. Your Azure AD tenant ID.
2. The client application ID of the app registration you created in Azure AD.
3. A client secret, you need to create this in the app registration in the Certificates & Secrets blade.
4. The URL to your Azure Digital Twins instance.